# Different images for different languages in multilingual stores without 3rd party software

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

As above, I hope that visitors who  select different stores can see different images. I have all the text translated and I don't want to rely on 3rd party app. I have come across this thread: https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/how-can-upload-different-images-based-on-the-different-store/m-p/1007146

There is one reply that mentioned this is possible; but I can't find any other resources on the matter above. Appreciate if anyone can guide me through on the process.

Answer (score 2):

on code is not really hard, but is boring to maintain.

1. you should upload your images by settings/files.
2. on the folder Locales of your theme you have the languages JSON files. Create inside an object "images" and there create the keys you need, and set as value the link you have from step 1.
3. On your template use liquid translation to translate the image address it will manage to change the file address. done!

EX: on pseudo code:

file: locales/en.default.json

```js
{
  "images": {
    "sliders": {
      "1": "slider_1_en.jpg",
      "2": "slider_2_en.jpg"
    }
  }
  // .... rest of the file 
}
```

file: locales/es.json

```js
{
  "images": {
    "sliders": {
      "1": "slider_1_es.jpg",
      "2": "slider_2_es.jpg"
  }
  // .... rest of the file 
}
```

IMPORTANT: save the name of the file including the extension. `slider_1_es` not works. It should be `slider_1_es.jpg`.

Do the same on all the languages you use

Now on any liquid file were you need the translated image, you can do a simple image:

```html
<img
 src="{{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '1500x' }}"
 loading="lazy"
>
```

Or even somethin more complex using srcset:

```html
<img
  srcset="
   {{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '375x' }} 375w,
   {{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '750x' }} 750w,
   {{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '1100x' }} 1100w,
   {{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '1500x' }} 1500w,
   {{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '1780x' }} 1780w,
   {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '2000x' }} 2000w
 "
 sizes="(min-width: 750px) calc(100vw - 22rem), 1100px"
 src="{{ 'images.sliders.1' | t | file_img_url: '1500x' }}"
 loading="lazy"
>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the above, for the liquid file edit, where should it be put? 
Say the following is the liquid-banner.liquid file:

https://ibb.co/WHgNWdX

I am a bit uncertain where the line in liquid file should be located at.

Comment: Also @chefjuanpi - just to confirm - this is how locale json file should look like right? 

https://ibb.co/Ltrwr1G

Comment: you're modifiying the schema file, you should modify the language file usually is `en.default.json`. I edit my response adding more details to easy understanding.

Comment: Many thanks - it gave me a sense how to proceed from here: 

By the way, with srcset you have here I think there's stg wrong, if I follow suit what you wrote here - the image won't load at all.

I have put a pastebin here (from original - how to edit to fit the purpose): 
https://pastebin.com/URfnhbBN